# MySQL binlogs seems incomplete?

Tags: mysql

I created a Database, a table and inserted some data, and found this `binlog.0000001` in my log folder, but when I do `mysqlbinlog binlog.0000001`, it only shows stuff below, seems incomplete: (There's only two files in the log dir: `binlog.000001  binlog.index`)

```
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
#120924 21:12:56 server id 1  end_log_pos 107   Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log created 120924 21:12:56 at startup
# Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.
ROLLBACK/*!*/;
BINLOG '
GAVhUA8BAAAAZwAAAGsAAAABAAQANS41LjI0LTB1YnVudHUwLjEyLjA0LjEtbG9nAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYBWFQEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAVAAEGggAAAAICAgCAA==
'/*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
```

If this warning was the cause: `Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.`.

How do I force `close` the log?

**EDIT**

After `flush logs` command, I see "0 rows" affected, and a few new files, `binlog.000001  binlog.000002  binlog.000003  binlog.000004  binlog.index`, the contents are nearly the same as `binlog.000001`.

Now I dropped the database, and try restore it with `mysqlbinlog binlog.0* | mysql -u root -p`, but the database wasn't recovered.

**EDIT 2**

```
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

log-bin=/var/log/mysql/binlog
binlog-do-db=mydb

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
```

P.S /var/log/mysql{.err,.log} are both empty

Comment: The `FLUSH LOGS` command will flush any remaining data, close the current log file and open a new log file.

Comment: @ErikA doesn't seem to work, maybe I've missed something

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place for your binlogs?

Comment: Do you have any `binlog-do-db` or `binlog-ignore-db` statements in your `my.cnf`? Actually, could you just post the `[mysqld]` portion of that file?

Comment: @ErikA right, the name differ, I specified 'mydb', but didn't see anything prefixed with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binlog-do-db=mydb
```

> @ErikA right, the name differ, I specified 'mydb', but didn't see
>   anything prefixed with that

Which binlog format are you using: statement-based or row-based?

- Statement-based logging: only statements which has default database
  is `mydb` are written to binary log.
- Row-based logging: only changes to table belonging to `mydb` are
  logged, the default database has no effect.

Take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db) for more details.

> P.S `/var/log/mysql{.err,.log}` are both empty

Specify a [`log-error`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-error) option under the [`mysqld`] section, then restart MySQL and try again.